# How do you create a string representation of an in-order traversal that is recursive?

Tags: python, string, recursion, binary-search-tree, traversal

I have to create and return a string representation of the in-order traversal of a Binary Search Tree. Below I do have the in order traversal, but I can not figure out how to change this into string form. I did try using + to concatenate them together, however it doesn't run on the terminal. I can also post my whole BST code if need. Please and thank you.

```
def in_order(self):
    if self.__root is not None:
        self._in(self.__root)

def _in(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return
    if root is not None:
        self._in(root.lchild)
        print(str(root.value)) 
        self._in(root.rchild)
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate and return:

```
def in_order(self):
    if self.__root is not None:      
        return self._in(self.__root)

def _in(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return ''

    if root is not None:
        left = self._in(root.lchild)
        right = self._in(root.rchild)
        return left + ' ' + str(root.value) + ' ' + right
```

You have to print the result of calling `obj.in_order()`: `print(obj.in_order())`. If you want them one per line, replace `' '` with `'\n'` in both of its occurrences.

Comment: So in the terminal the code I had would give back the numbers in order, but one per line. When I tried to concatenate like you told me the terminal now gives nothing back